# MongoDB's $elemMatch does not find the proper result

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Below is a small MongoDB database:

```
> db.sss.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543f53b8711761110238be74"),
    "name" : "A",
    "pos" : 828288,
    "s_type" : 1,
    "sub_name" : "B01",
    "type" : "Test",
    "x_type" : 7,
    "chr" : [
        {
            "5" : "C"
        },
        {
            "6" : "T"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543f53b8711761110238be75"),
    "name" : "A",
    "pos" : 171878,
    "s_type" : 3,
    "sub_name" : "B01",
    "type" : "Test",
    "x_type" : 8,
    "chr" : [
        {
            "5" : "C"
        },
        {
            "6" : "T"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543f53b8711761110238be76"),
    "name" : "A",
    "pos" : 871963,
    "s_type" : 3,
    "sub_name" : "B01",
    "type" : "Test",
    "x_type" : 9,
    "chr" : [
        {
            "5" : "A"
        },
        {
            "6" : "G"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543f53b8711761110238be77"),
    "name" : "A",
    "pos" : 1932523,
    "s_type" : 1,
    "sub_name" : "B01",
    "type" : "Test",
    "x_type" : 10,
    "chr" : [
        {
            "4" : "T"
        },
        {
            "5" : "A"
        },
        {
            "6" : "X"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543f53b8711761110238be78"),
    "name" : "A",
    "pos" : 667214,
    "s_type" : 1,
    "sub_name" : "B01",
    "type" : "Test",
    "x_type" : 14,
    "chr" : [
        {
            "4" : "T"
        },
        {
            "5" : "G"
        },
        {
            "6" : "G"
        }
    ]
}
```

The above database has been created with below script:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from collections import defaultdict


db = MongoClient().test
sDB = db.sss

r = [["Test", "A", "B01", 828288,  1,    7, 'C', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 828288,  1,    7, 'T', 6],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 171878,  3,    8, 'C', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 171878,  3,    8, 'T', 6],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 871963,  3,    9, 'A', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 871963,  3,    9, 'G', 6],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'T', 4],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'A', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'X', 6],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'T', 4],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'G', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'G', 6]]

for i in r:
    sDB.update({'type': i[0],
          'name': i[1],
          'sub_name': i[2],
          'pos': i[3],
          's_type': i[4],
          'x_type': i[5]},
          {"$push": {"chr":{str(i[7]): i[6]} }}, True)
```

I started to write a query for the following conditions:

- `x_type:7` and `x_type:9` are correct, because `chr.5` and `chr.6` have different characters and neither of them has a character X.
- `x_type:8` would be correct, but is out of range (200000 to 2000000)
- `x_type:10` is not valid, because `chr.6` contain a X
- `x_type:14` is not valid, because `chr.5` and `chr.6` have the same characters

However, I did not get what I wanted with the following draft query:

```
> db.snps.find({"pos": {$gte: 200000, $lt: 2000000}}, {"chr":{$elemMatch:{"6":{$ne: "X"}}}}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543f53b8711761110238be74"),
    "chr" : [
        {
            "5" : "C"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543f53b8711761110238be76"),
    "chr" : [
        {
            "5" : "A"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543f53b8711761110238be77"),
    "chr" : [
        {
            "4" : "T"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543f53b8711761110238be78"),
    "chr" : [
        {
            "4" : "T"
        }
    ]
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is sample Output..!!!!

Comment: a sample output would be `{"name" : "A", "pos" : 828288, "s_type" : 1, "sub_name" : "B01", "type" : "Test", "x_type" : 7}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the wrong form of [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) here as what you are using is the "projection" form and is used to select the **first** match in the array to the conditions that you supply. The only "query" condition you have specified here is that the "pos" value falls within the requested range.

If what you want is that *both* the conditions are present where the document has a "pos" value within the range and that there is no "X" value in "chr.6". The final and additional clause is a little tricky as you are comparing values of array elements. But this is possible with the JavaScript evaluation of [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) and fairly simple as long as there are only and always two elements:

```js
db.snps.find({
    "pos": { "$gte": 200000, "$lt": 2000000 },
    "chr.6": { "$ne": "X" },
    "$where": "this.chr[0]['5'] != this.chr[1]['6']"
})
```

A bit more tricky for other combinations or named elements but the same principles of JavaScript evaluation apply to that condition.

So you don't need the query form of [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) here due to only testing one field of the array elements, and projection is therefore in the wrong place. What you want a "query" conditions that select the documents that meet them.

Comment: Thank you, I tried unsuccessfully to add that there should be no "X" value in "chr.5" or "chr.6" with the following query 
`db.snps.find({"pos": { "$gte": 200000, "$lt": 2000000 },{"$or" :[{"chr.5": { "$ne": "X" }, "chr.6": {"$ne": "X"}}]}, "$where": "this.chr[0]['5'] != this.chr[1]['6']" })`.
In order to check whether `where` would work with lists which contains more than two elements I deleted the condition that no X are permit. However, I did not get additional `x_type:10`.

Comment: @user977828 I and others can only really answer based on how you present your question. If you have another question or different conditions then you really should post another question. The query conditions as shown above should meet the conditions you specified in your question.